# CNN output shape explanation

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, cnn, convolution

I have the following sequential model:

```
model = models.Sequential()
model.add(Reshape(([1]+in_shp), input_shape=in_shp))
model.add(ZeroPadding2D((0, 2)))
model.add(Conv2D(256, (1, 3),padding='valid', activation="relu", name="conv1",data_format="channels_first", kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform'))
model.add(Dropout(dr))
model.add(ZeroPadding2D((0, 2)))
model.add(Conv2D(80, (2, 3), padding="valid", activation="relu", name="conv2",data_format="channels_first", kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform'))
model.add(Dropout(dr))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', name="dense1"))
model.add(Dropout(dr))
model.add(Dense( len(classes), kernel_initializer='he_normal', name="dense2" ))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))
model.add(Reshape([len(classes)]))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam')
model.summary()
```

and I got the following summary:

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
reshape_1 (Reshape)          (None, 1, 2, 128)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
zero_padding2d_1 (ZeroPaddin (None, 1, 6, 128)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv1 (Conv2D)               (None, 256, 6, 126)       1024      
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_1 (Dropout)          (None, 256, 6, 126)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
zero_padding2d_2 (ZeroPaddin (None, 256, 10, 126)      0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2 (Conv2D)               (None, 80, 9, 124)        122960    
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_2 (Dropout)          (None, 80, 9, 124)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_1 (Flatten)          (None, 89280)             0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense1 (Dense)               (None, 256)               22855936  
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_3 (Dropout)          (None, 256)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense2 (Dense)               (None, 8)                 2056      
_________________________________________________________________
activation_1 (Activation)    (None, 8)                 0         
_________________________________________________________________
reshape_2 (Reshape)          (None, 8)                 0         
=================================================================
Total params: 22,981,976
Trainable params: 22,981,976
Non-trainable params: 0
```

The model works fine. But, I want to understand something regarding `conv1` layer. Why the width value has been reduced from 128 to 126? I am really confused about that shouldn't it be the same value as the previous layer?

Also, the same thing for the `conv2` layer too where the height and width have decreased from (10,126) to (9,124).

Could someone explain me why?

Comment: I guess you have valid convolution. if you want that to be $128$ set convolution to be same.

Comment: @Media : after you pointed me to the padding parameter (`same` or `valid`). i digged a little bit and i understood why in the first conv layer it dropped from **128** to **126** but it does not really make sense for the second layer to drop from **126** to **124** or from **10** to **9**

Comment: They are valid too. It pads those layers too.

Comment: +1 to Media, when windows are cut off by the input (image?) edges, the number of windows is smaller than the width of the input.  But also, you appear to be trying to zero-pad before the conv layers, and those appear to be padding in the wrong dimensions; try specifying `data_format` in the padding layers too, or just skip those layers in favor of padding inside the conv layers.

Comment: i draw a small example and Now i understand Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the convolution layer, the filter (*3x3* in your case) is applied to the images in order to produce the output (feature map) and is slid to the right and bottom by a parameter called stride (in your case, it is not defined, the default is 1). Now if `padding='valid'`, the output dimension will change, but if you change it to `padding='same'`, the output dimension will be the same as input and this is because of the idea of zero padding (i.e., padding image borders with zero).

Answer (score 2):

It is because of the kind of convolution you've used. It is a `valid` convolution. If you want the output to be $128$, set the convolution to be `same`. Consider that this is also applicable to the deep layers too. They also can have either of these convolutions.